# bouncing marker, not bouncing after zoom

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

this issue I had with google maps, I made a [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/tinybyte/Hq5U6/).

```
marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latlng, 
        map: map, 
        animation: google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE,
        title:"Hello World!"
    }),
```

if I drag the map where I can no longer see the marker, and zoom-in (usually 3 or 4 levels), after I zoom-out where I'm able to see my marker, It's not bouncing anymore, if I click on it, it will bounce again.

is this a browser issue, what am I facing here?

Comment: Strange. It seems like `click` event is triggered when the map is zoom out enough. See [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Hq5U6/1/). When you zoom in and click on marker two messages are delivered from event handler in console log.

Comment: did you see the marker still sits still!

Comment: Yes. If someone doesn't find explanation for it than it could be reported as an issue.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is the default behavior of Google Marker animation. Since you left the map extent there's no need to continue the animation behind the scenes.

If you really want to have your marker bouncing whenever you see it you can add the 'bounds_changed' map event. Every time you zoom or drag the map it should check if your marker is within the visible map area and if so, refresh the bounce behavior:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'bounds_changed', function(event) {

    if(map.getBounds().contains(marker.position)){

        marker.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);
    };
});
```